# Flex, AIR: Search for .pdf files in specified folder

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I need ActionScriot code that will parse a given folder and search it for .txt files. Any links or code samples will be helpful. (Adobe Flex 3.3/AIR)

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There:

```
var docs:File = File.documentsDirectory;
var dirs:Array = docs.getDirectoryListing();
var pdfFiles:String = "";
for(var i:int; i < dirs.length; i++)
{
    var f:File = dirs[i] as File;
    if(f.isDirectory || f.name.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(".pdf") != f.name.length - 4)
        continue;

    pdfFiles += f.name + "\n";
}
txt.text = pdfFiles;
```