# Actionscript 3 search for file in a directory, return path

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a pretty basic understanding of actionscript and how to write a little bit of code with it, but I'm struggling on how to attack this problem.

We have a application that runs a bunch of BIRT reports. They are currently stored in a reports/ folder. Lately we've been getting more and more and we need to refactor these into subfolders for the various departments.

```
Reports/
    Campus 1/
        Budget Office/
             report1.rptdesign
             report2.rptdesign
        Human Resources/
    Campus 2
    Campus 3
```

How can I get a path name to a specific report if I know the report name and that it is somewhere within the reports/* directory?

For example if the user selected report2.rptdesign, how can I get back the path "reports/campus1/budget office/"?

A url of an example or sample code to at least get me going in the right direction would be a huge help, thanks!

I did find this [Flex, AIR: Search for .pdf files in specified folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384950/flex-air-search-for-pdf-files-in-specified-folder), not sure if that what I need though.

Comment: How does the user select the report?

Comment: The report names are stored in an oracle database that is served up through a flex front end. The only time the directory is needed is when the user chooses to run said report, at which point our LaunchReportCommand.as fires. The problem is the path is hard coded to  "frameset?_report=reports/", and it needs to be changed based on the selected report. Hope that all makes sense

Comment: This seems like a good starting point http://www.wuup.co.uk/as3-basics-list-all-files-in-a-folder-including-subdirectories-air

Comment: Small problem with that is that the flash.filesystem.* libraries are only available on the Desktop, this is a web application.

Comment: If the files are stored locally to the clients machine, you will have no way of verifying the integrity of the data. If the files are stored on a server then all you should have to do is add a field into your database table which has the location of the file.

Comment: The files are stored on a server, I was hoping I wouldn't need to change anything on the database when all I need to do in theory is have the path change based on where the report is found. I might try and see if our Java side could do the recursive search and then just pass the path back over to the Flex side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then having recursive search in java, try increasing a filed in DB. This approach will be better.You will be calling the service from flex to get the reports from server which will return you a Collection some what like this sample.

```
    <reports>
    <report>
        <fileName> report1.rptdesign</fileName>
        <filePath>Campus 1/Budget Office/report1.rptdesign</filePath>
    </report>
    <report>
        <fileName> report1.rptdesign</fileName>
        <filePath>Campus 1/Human Resources/report1.rptdesign</filePath>
    </report>
    <report>
        <fileName> report1.rptdesign</fileName>
        <filePath>Campus 2/Budget Office/report1.rptdesign</filePath>
    </report>
    <report>
        <fileName> report1.rptdesign</fileName>
        <filePath>Campus 2/Human Resources/report1.rptdesign</filePath>
    </report>
</reports>
```

this will save one call to sever on user interaction.

Comment: Ended up using a switch statement and standardizing the naming of the reports.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get a path name to a specific report if I know the report name and that it is somewhere within the reports/* directory?

Pretty sure you can't do that in the browser.